# Как запускать разные HTML в одном gulp проекте

Tags: html, node.js, gulp, npm

Есть проект *gulp*, в нем есть один `index.html`, теперь нужно создать второй `second.html`.
Вопрос знатокам. Как запускать через *gulp*, разные HTML?
Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в адресной строке прописать после http://localhost:8888/secondindex.html

8888 - примерное значение хоста.Значение может быть у каждого своё.

secondindex.html - Имя вашего другого модуля